# Is there any Mediawiki Api through which I can know the image duplicates?

Tags: mediawiki

I am trying to reduce the size of the storage used. I want to know is there any way through which I can know if the file already exists and get its path if not then save the image.

Answer (score 1):

In `special pages` page, you can find `List of files with duplicates`.

Through the [API query action](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query) you can extract a standard property called `duplicatefiles` that can be used in combination with a generator `allimages`

```
 api.php?action=query&generator=allimages&prop=duplicatefiles
```

Comment: I want to do it programatically. Any API you know that can help me out?

Comment: My bad. Added the API part